# How to handle Errors with the Apollo stack

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollostack, apollo-server, apollo-client

I'm using the Apollo Stack with `graphql-server-express` and `apollo-client`.

Because my backend is not perfect errors can appear and therefore I have to respond to a request with an error for that path.

Till now my main problem was authentication and therefore I responded with an error.

```
return new Error(`${data.status}: ${data.statusText} @ ${data.url}`)
```

In the frontend I use apollo-client to query data.

```
return apollo
        .query({query: gql`
            query {
                ${query}
            }`,
            forceFetch: forceFetch
        })
        .then(result => { debugger; return result.data })
        .catch(error => { debugger; console.error(error); });
```

But if one property of the query responds with an error, only the catch function will be invoked.
Even the data of the remaining properties is transferred, I see this in the network tab of the Chrome Dev Tools. In is not error object in the catch function.

My attempt works fine with GraphiQL where I get the errors and data in the same object.

So how can I throw errors for a property without loosing the whole request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could manually look for `result.error` in the `then` part of your promise and avoid the use of `catch`. Also *I think* you could also add a `then` after the `catch` call to handle this specific case.

In addition to that, you can also use [formatError](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-server/setup.html#graphqlOptions) in your GraphQL server to manually filter and format error messages. The body of that function is the following, and you have access to the thrown `Error`.

```
formatError: (error) => {
  return {
    name: error.name,
    mensaje: error.message
  }
}
```